# Why does _Beneath Apple DOS_ show FM encoding rather than GCR?

Tags: apple-ii, floppy-disk

From the beginning in 1978 the Apple II floppy disk system used [GCR
encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_coded_recording#Apple) to convert data bytes to sequences of binary values to
be written to the diskette: first 4-and-4 encoding (never released),
then 5-and-3 encoding (DOS 3.1 through 3.2.1 13-sector), and later
6-and-2 encoding (DOS 3.3 16-sector).

Starting on [page 3-3](https://archive.org/details/Beneath_Apple_DOS_OCR/page/n13/mode/1up)¹ of Worth and Lechner's *Beneath Apple
DOS* they describe the format of bits on the track. They mention that
they're discussing the actual analogue signals, only the digital 1s
and 0s, and say that, "For the purposes of this discussion the
demarcation of these intervals will be depicted by a clock bit,"
indicating that what they describe might be slightly different from
what's really being written to or read from the diskette.

However, what they describe there and show in figure 3.2 is clearly FM
encoding, with a clock bit before each data bit, rather than GCR:

[image: figure 3.2]

Is this just flat-out wrong, or oversimplified, or am I missing
something here? If it's not simply wrong, how does this affect the
later discussion of normal bytes vs. self-sync bytes and
synchronization in the gaps between the fields, particularly with
regard to figure 3.10 on page 3-9, showing how one can start reading
at any bit in a series of (10-bit) sync bytes and recover the byte
alignment within 5 bytes?

[image: figure 3.10]

---

¹<sub>I've linked to the 1982 Fourth Printing edition here, but the
content of this section is the same in substance in the [1983 Fifth
Printing](https://archive.org/details/Beneath_Apple_DOS_alt/page/n7/mode/1up), "Updated for Apple IIe."</sub>

Comment: I also was reading it recently, and am tempted to side with "flat-out wrong", especially for: "The diagrams are a representation of what functionally occurs within the disk drive. For the purposes of our presentation, the hardware interface to the diskette will be represented as an eight bit "data latch".", which taken with figure 3.5 seems to imply that the author thought that an FM-esque scheme was always in use, with data/clock separation occurring in the drive?

Comment: One more vote for "flat-out wrong". Because it is. Although it's not really true that the content is substantially the same in the Fifth Printing - there were significant corrections.

Comment: @TeaRex Regarding content changes, you did notice that I wrote "in this section," right? If there were substantial changes I missed, perhaps you could post an answer clarifying that, since I think that would definitely contribute to answering the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is "flat out wrong", they do preface this with:

> As this manual is primarily concerned with software, **no attempt will
>   be made to deal with the specifics of the hardware**. For example, while
>   in fact data is stored as a continuous stream of analog signals, we
>   will deal with discrete digital data, i.e. a or a 1 . We recognize
>   that the hardware converts analog data to digital data but how this is
>   accomplished is beyond the scope of this manual.

The diagram and surrounding text were updated in the [Fifth Printing, March 1983](https://archive.org/details/Beneath_Apple_DOS_alt/page/n7/mode/2up):

> Data bits are recorded on the diskette in precise intervals. The
>   hardware recognizes each of these intervals as either a or a 1 . We
>   will define these intervals to be "bit cells". A bit cell can be
>   thought of as the distance the diskette moves in four machine cycles,
>   which is about four microseconds. Using this representation, data
>   written to and read back from the diskette takes the form shown in
>   Figure 3.2. The data pattern shown represents a binary value of 101.

The figure they refer to is actually now Figure 3.3:

[image]

As for why the authors originally showed FM encoding, we can only presume that they were aware that current disk drives used that and unaware that the Disk II didn't. It's probably not a coincidence that the above correction to the text was made around the same time that their publisher was about to release Sather's [Understanding the Apple II](https://archive.org/details/Understanding_the_Apple_II_1983_Quality_Software/mode/2up), which contained the first complete and detailed analysis of the disk system hardware.

Comment: Ah! I'd glanced at the 5th edition but didn't look closely enough to see that they'd changed the diagrams to completely remove the clock bits (which I now know, through further research, to be spurious). I find it somewhat ironic that a few pages later in the 4th edition in [Figure 3.13](https://archive.org/stream/Beneath_Apple_DOS_OCR#page/n22/mode/1up) they show FM coding exactly as it's used in the sector address fields.

Answer (score 2):

The first figure is flat-out wrong. Only the "D" bits they've marked
are stored on the diskette as the presence (D=1) or absence (D=0) of a
magnetic flux change. Those clock bits exist neither on the diskette
nor in the internals of the controller. (The controller does have its
own separate clock signals, but these are independent and never
intermixed with the data bits.)

The second digram gives an accurate picture of what's stored on the
diskette: a stream of `1` and `0` bits encoded as a flux change or
lack of a flux change.

That said, as well as GCR encoding for the sector data fields, the
Disk II system *did* use FM encoding for the sector address fields as
is shown later in *Beneath Apple DOS* and below. To understand how
this worked we need to understand how the controller (with some
assistance from software) reads data from the diskette and divides it
up into bytes.

#### Byte Framing

To start reading, the shift register that holds the read data is
cleared (set to $00) and the controller starts in a state that Jim
Sather calls "QA WAIT,"¹ where it is waiting for a `1` bit (i.e., a
flux transition) to appear. Once a `1` appears, it clocks that and
next seven bits (`1`s or `0`s) into the shift register. The software
is expected to continuously test bit 7 of the shift register for the
appearance of that initial `1` bit and take that as the signal that a
full byte has been read. In the mean time, after it finishes reading a
byte the controller has re-entered QA WAIT and will leave the shift
register alone until another `1` bit appears. Shortly after that it
will clear the shift register and start clocking in another byte.

This explains why bytes stored on the disk must always start with a
`1` bit: that's what triggers the start of the shift register load
sequence. When starting to read a series of bytes the controller will
start at a random bit (most likely in the middle of a byte); the
"autosync" sequence of bits in the second figure in the question shows
how, via ignoring `0` bits when starting a byte read, the controller
can sync to the byte boundaries of data being read from the diskette.
(The `0` values in that figure not covered by the braces underneath
are the ones ignored while in the QA WAIT state.)

That bytes must start with a `1` bit is particular to how the Disk II
controller assembles bytes. The other major limitation, that there may
not be more than two `0` bits in a row within a byte, is a general
limitation of reading self-clocked data from a variable speed medium.²

#### FM vs. GCR Encoding

The two major limitations above determine that only a subset of all
bytes valued $00 to $FF can be reliably read from a diskette; the byte
values that can be used always start with a `1` in the most
significant bit and never have more than two (or in DOS 3.2 or
earlier, one) `0` bits in a row.

This allows for use of both FM and GCR encoding, and in fact Apple DOS
uses both. On [page 3-12](https://archive.org/stream/Beneath_Apple_DOS_OCR#page/n22/mode/1up) of *Beneath Apple DOS* they show the format
of the address field for each sector:

[image: Figure 3.13: Address Field]

As you can see, the bytes encoding the volume, track, sector and
checksum are in a version of FM encoding: each byte is a series of `1`
bits alternating with data bits. (The data bits are ordered the way
they are to make decoding easier: left-shift the XX byte, loading `1`
into the LSB, and AND the result with it with the YY byte.)

For the data field for each sector, however, a GCR encoding is used.

Note that the sync, prologue, and epilogue bytes are not "encoded" at
all; they are simply raw bit patterns that follow the rules above but
are invalid  in either encoding,³ allowing the system to recognize
them as "control bytes" rather than any kind of data.

#### Other Encodings

From the above you can see that the Disk II system seems also, with
appropriate software, probably capable of reading diskettes using
Shugart's [standard single-density soft-sectored formats](https://archive.org/stream/bitsavers_shugartSA4eManualApr1979_2873568#page/n9/mode/1up)
that use FM encoding, such as 18 × 128 byte sectors per track (78.75
KB).⁴

However, the limitations above also indicate why an Apple II cannot
read any of the double-density [MFM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_frequency_modulation) standard formats: they encoded
data in such a way that some bytes could start with a `0`, and the
Disk II controller cannot sync to those (though a different controller
could be designed to do so using the same drive).

---

¹<sub>Jim Sather, *Understanding the Apple II*, [Figure 9.16](https://archive.org/stream/Understanding_the_Apple_II_1983_Quality_Software#page/n260/mode/1up).
Chapter 9 is a good but *very* detailed (42 dense pages) description
of the Disk II hardware and software; here I attempt to give an
accurate but limited description of just the parts relevant to the
question.</sub>

²<sub>The limitation for DOS 3.2 and earlier is one `0` bit; this is
due to using a different state machine in the first generation of
controllers. Generically, the particular number of `0` bits in a row
that are allowed will depend on the design of a particular system and
how much accuracy it loses as it goes longer without flux transitions, but
system designers will always set a particular limit.</sub>

³<sub>Actually the middle $AA is valid FM of half a byte, but would
never be read as such because the preceding byte is not valid FM. The
trailing $EB is actually never fully written; see *Understanding the
Apple II* for details.</sub>

⁴<sub>The data rate must also be the same, of course. This is limited
by the media itself, which is probably why common controllers such as
the Western Digital [FD1791](https://archive.org/stream/WesternDigitalFD1791Datasheet#page/n16/mode/1up) and Fujitsu [MB8866](https://archive.org/stream/MB8866Datasheet#page/n9/mode/1up) use the FM data rate
established by the IBM 3740 format: 125 kHz, or 4 μs for the clock bit
and 4 μs for the data bit. The Disk II system uses 4 clock cycles per
bit, which at 1.023 MHz is very close to 4 μs.</sub>

Comment: Re: "probably capable of reading diskettes using Shugart's standard single-density soft-sectored formats." Wouldn't this require identical data rates (number of bit cells per second)? Or are they close enough to make it possible?

Comment: @TeaRex Good point! I had assumed the raw bit rates would be very similar since, given that they're limited by the media, there's no reason to use less than the highest commonly accepted reliable rate. But I've done some research on this and added a footnote addressing the issue directly.